# Options for correcting improper deck beam to post attachments

Tags: deck, post, beam

We purchased a house with a large deck where the post to beam connections look exactly like the prohibited configuration shown here:[image: picture showing beams on either side of post and bolted through instead of beams on top of post]

The 6 x 6 posts are all attached to concrete footings using the typical Simpson style post base connectors.  I am looking for options on how to correct the problem.  I have considered simply bolting or nailing a 2 x 6 to the side of each post under each beam but I am hoping there is a simpler, less kludgy solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to mount a support column to a deck and to a header?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75978/what-is-the-right-way-to-mount-a-support-column-to-a-deck-and-to-a-header)

Comment: Note, the ledger board is to be doubled up; sandwiched next to each other. I guess at this point you could get away with a bracket on both sides. Or an additional ledger added to the front, leaving the one that does nothing (not supported by a bracket) back there.

Comment: If that link does not provide the answer you're looking for, or if you have any concerns about it, please provide a picture at this junction of your deck. I, myself would also like to make sure everything's on the up-and-up.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you need to meet local codes, you should ask the inspector what your options are. If you're concerned about safety, just add another pair of bolts to each connection and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

If the deck is 2' off the ground or less, I wouldn't be overly concerned about it. Otherwise, if they are already existing the easiest way would be to use hardware designed for this kind of connection.

### However!

Keep in mind that a beam that consists of two 2-bys means the two 2-bys are sandwiched together and nailed together so they share their loads and reduce twisting, deflection, etc...

This means that your beam might not actually be properly size either, which is not a problem a bracket can fix for you. You might need a bracket AND more 2-bys. That or just redo it properly instead of trying to fix it.